# Count of radio buttons not working, redirected to first activity automatically when clicking on button

Tags: java, android, android-studio, radio-button

I am trying to get the number of radio button checked for my android app. I have 15 radio buttons in my app, and I am just trying to count for the first 8 of them. "test" is the EditText component, in which I am trying to display the number of radio buttons selected. `FinalSubmit` is the button on which listener has been implemented. Below is the code for the radio buttons, and the code which I am using in the `onClickListener`:

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    RadioButton rb1, rb2, rb3, rb4, rb5, rb6, rb7, rb8, rb9, rb10, rb11, rb12, rb13, rb14, rb15;

    int rbChecked = 0;

    Button finalsubmit;
    EditText test;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        finalsubmit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
        test = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        rb1 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
        rb2 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);
        rb3 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton3);
        rb4 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton4);
        rb5 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton5);
        rb6 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton6);
        rb7 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton7);
        rb8 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton8);
        rb9 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton9);
        rb10 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton10);
        rb11 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton11);
        rb12 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton12);
        rb13 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton13);
        rb14 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton14);
        rb15 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton15);

        finalsubmit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (rb1.isChecked()) {rbChecked++;}
            if (rb2.isChecked()) {rbChecked++;}
            if (rb3.isChecked()) {rbChecked++;}
            if (rb4.isChecked()) {rbChecked++;}
            if (rb5.isChecked()) {rbChecked++;}
            if (rb6.isChecked()) {rbChecked++;}
            if (rb7.isChecked()) {rbChecked++;}
            if (rb8.isChecked()) {rbChecked++;}

            test.setText(rbChecked);
        }
    });
}
```

Now the problem is as soon as I am clicking on the submit button, either the app is getting crashed, or it is being redirected to the first activity of my app. Please, someone, help me, I have done the google and have gone through StackOverflow as well, but I am stuck. Below is the logcat for the same:

```
10-07 02:36:41.949 22873-22873/? I/edu.glanceandg: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
10-07 02:36:41.977 22873-22873/? W/edu.glanceandg: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
10-07 02:36:42.543 22873-22873/saferatestarter.dasnr.okstate.edu.glanceandgo I/edu.glanceandg: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
10-07 02:36:42.673 22873-22873/saferatestarter.dasnr.okstate.edu.glanceandgo W/edu.glanceandg: JIT profile information will not be recorded: profile file does not exits.
10-07 02:36:42.676 22873-22873/saferatestarter.dasnr.okstate.edu.glanceandgo I/chatty: uid=10085(saferatestarter.dasnr.okstate.edu.glanceandgo) identical 10 lines
10-07 02:36:42.676 22873-22873/saferatestarter.dasnr.okstate.edu.glanceandgo W/edu.glanceandg: JIT profile information will not be recorded: profile file does not exits.
10-07 02:36:42.819 22873-22873/saferatestarter.dasnr.okstate.edu.glanceandgo I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
10-07 02:36:43.045 22873-22873/saferatestarter.dasnr.okstate.edu.glanceandgo W/edu.glanceandg: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (light greylist, reflection)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (light greylist, reflection)
10-07 02:36:43.196 22873-22873/saferatestarter.dasnr.okstate.edu.glanceandgo D/OpenGLRenderer: HWUI GL Pipeline
10-07 02:36:43.286 22873-22893/saferatestarter.dasnr.okstate.edu.glanceandgo I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
10-07 02:36:43.287 22873-22893/saferatestarter.dasnr.okstate.edu.glanceandgo I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay retrieved: 0
10-07 02:36:43.287 22873-22893/saferatestarter.dasnr.okstate.edu.glanceandgo I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
10-07 02:36:43.287 22873-22893/saferatestarter.dasnr.okstate.edu.glanceandgo D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
10-07 02:36:43.288 22873-22893/saferatestarter.dasnr.okstate.edu.glanceandgo W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
10-07 02:36:43.288 22873-22893/saferatestarter.dasnr.okstate.edu.glanceandgo D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
10-07 02:36:43.368 22873-22893/saferatestarter.dasnr.okstate.edu.glanceandgo D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xe20a3ca0: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
10-07 02:36:43.524 22873-22893/saferatestarter.dasnr.okstate.edu.glanceandgo D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe20a3ca0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe79c7f40)
10-07 02:36:43.744 22873-22873/saferatestarter.dasnr.okstate.edu.glanceandgo I/Choreographer: Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-07 02:36:43.757 22873-22893/saferatestarter.dasnr.okstate.edu.glanceandgo D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe20a3ca0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe79c7f40)
10-07 02:36:44.001 22873-22893/saferatestarter.dasnr.okstate.edu.glanceandgo I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=765ms; Flags=0, IntendedVsync=18745452302779, Vsync=18745952302759, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=18745962995820, AnimationStart=18745963051180, PerformTraversalsStart=18745963478560, DrawStart=18745966259640, SyncQueued=18745974869130, SyncStart=18745976723540, IssueDrawCommandsStart=18745979342070, SwapBuffers=18746138382050, FrameCompleted=18746219897500, DequeueBufferDuration=257000, QueueBufferDuration=464000, 
10-07 02:36:44.047 22873-22873/saferatestarter.dasnr.okstate.edu.glanceandgo I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 6728 bytes, containing 1 windows, 25 views
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys, I did a blunder, below is the change which I made. Now its working perfectly fine:

```
test.setText(String.valueOf(rbChecked));
```

Comment: Good to know you have corrected the problem by yourself. Mark your own answer as correct to let others know that you have solved it.